# Reloading loaded html in div with new parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I have been struggling with this problem for ages.

I have an `index.html` with a `<div id="mirador"></div>`. This html page also has a search form as so:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="search-bar">
        <form class="searchBar">
          <div class="row" >
            <div class="allElements">
                <div class="input-group" >
                  <span style="color:black" class="input-group-addon">
                      <select onchange="getValues(this.value)">
                        <option>Choose Category</option>
                        <option>All</option>
                        <option>Author</option>
                        <option>Deed Date</option>
                        <option>Person</option>
                        <option>Place</option>
                        <option>Register Reference</option>
                        <option>Subject</option>
                      </select>
                  </span>
                  <div class="autocomplete" style ="width:400px">
                  <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Choose a category" style ="width:400px" disabled=true>
                  </div>

                  <span class="input-group-addon" style="color:black"> <button type="button" onclick="doSparql(this.value)">Search</button></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I wanted to load another html page within `index.html` so I used:

```
$("#mirador").load("mirador.html", function(){
             $("#mirador #loadedManifest").html("http://localhost:3001/api/manifests/"+searchReq);
            });
```

In this page `mirador.html` I included a div called `loadedManifest` to pass the search item and show the associated manifest. The problem is that the first time I perform the search the manifest loads perfectly but if I perform another search, the mirador instance is shown with no preloaded manifest. Can someone illuminate me what I am doing wrong? I think it has to do with something related to the instance. I tried to do `$(#mirador).empty()` but doesn't work. Here is the code for `mirador.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mirador-2.6.1/css/mirador-combined.css">
  <title>Mirador Viewer</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    #viewer {width: 50%; height: 85%; bottom:0px; right: 20px; position: absolute; }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewer"></div>
  <div id="loadedManifest" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
  <script src="mirador-2.6.1/mirador.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(function() {

      Mirador({
 
        "id": "viewer",
        "layout": "1x1",
    "mainMenuSettings" :
    {


      "show": true,
      "userLogo": {"label": "IIIF", "attributes": {"href": "http://iiif.io"}},
             
    },
    'showAddFromURLBox' : true,
    "saveSession": true,
        "data": [
     { "manifestUri": "http://localhost:3001/api/manifests/R494Vol1", "location": 'Notarial Archives Valletta'},
      { "manifestUri": "http://localhost:3001/api/manifests/MS588", "location": 'Notarial Archives Valletta'}
 
        ],
        "windowObjects": [{
          "loadedManifest" : document.getElementById("loadedManifest").innerHTML, 
          "viewType" : "ImageView"}],
    /** Testing Annotations **/
    
    annotationEndpoint: {
    name: 'Simple Annotation Store Endpoint',
    module: 'SimpleASEndpoint',
    options: {
     url: 'annotation',
      storeId: 'comparison',
      APIKey: 'user_auth'
    }
    }
      });
 
    });
 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you reload a html page all scripts stop executing, including the callback function that you defined.

Comment: Is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: @Hannah If your webpage is static I am worried there isn't a way to keep your javascript running when reloading the webpage. If you're calling an API you could always look into AJAX which helps you get data without reloading your webpage.

Comment: Am I not using AJAX to load mirador.html?

Comment: If you really want to reload the whole page you can set a cookie before reloading, and read the cookie after reloading. But why would you even want to reload when you already know the form values? It seems like you are using a PHP workflow.